# Cross-entropy loss influence over F-score

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, caffe, loss-function, cross-entropy

I'm training an FCN (Fully Convolutional Network) and using "Sigmoid Cross Entropy" as a loss function.
my measurements are F-measure and MAE.
The Train/Dev Loss w.r.t #iteration graph is something like the below:
[image]
Although Dev loss has a slight increase after #Iter=2200, my measurements on Dev set have been improved up to near #iter = 10000. I want to know is it possible in machine learning at all? If F-measure has been improved, should the loss also be decreased? How do you explain it?

Every answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, **yes** it's possible.

How I would explain it is by reasoning on the Cross-Entropy loss and how it differs from the metrics. Loss Functions for classification, generally speaking, are used to optimize models relying on probabilities (0.1/0.9), while metrics usually use the predicted labels. (0/1)

- Assuming having *strong confidence* (close to 0 or to 1) in a model probability hypothesis, **a wrong prediction will greatly increase the loss** and have a **small decrease in F-measure**.
- Likewise, in the opposite scenario, a model with *low confidence* (e.g. 0.49/0.51) would have **a small impact on the loss function** (from a numerical perspective) and a **greater impact on the metrics**.

Plotting the distribution of your predictions would help to confirm this hypothesis.